# Contain content of 50% width horiz divs to an overall wrapper width (1200px)

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve an increasingly popular design - two 50% width divs aligned horizontally (.tile), but their content **across both divs** restricted to an overall *max* width (equal to the page wrapper for the rest of the site e.g. 1200px). I have them floated left to achieve horizontal alignment, each with contrasting colours. Picture a centered 'overlay' wrapper across the 2 divs. The code below hopefully explains my setup:

CSS

```
.full-width-row {
    width: 100%; // 100% of entire page so child divs bg color will stretch
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.tile {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px // hack to fill height of parent
}
.tile-content {
    padding: 5%;
}
.left {
    background: #FFC15E;
}
.right {
    background: #3E7F72;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="full-width-row">
    <div class="tile left">
        <div class="tile-content">

                    //CONTENT LEFT  

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile right">
        <div class="tile-content">

                    //CONTENT RIGHT

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The parent here (.full-width-row) is 100% of the whole window, so the bg colours of the 2 child divs will stretch the whole page. It's the content inside these children that I want to behave within a maximum, defined width (equal to 1200px). Has anyone built a similar layout or has any suggestions on how to achieve this?

*I guess the right-hand side div will never be a problem as it will always be in the 1200px wrapper space, but the left hand will keep moving left on bigger screens.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky one to explain but thanks for everyone's attempts. My solution was after all fairly straight forward. To the left hand side content class I also added a new class 'restrict'

```
.restrict {
    max-width: 600px;
    float: right;
}
```

This pushed the left side against a 'barrier of 600px from center (half the page wrapper), whilst keeping the colour of the parent 50% div to stretch the whole page. Ironically now that I've seen it I think I might just center both content div's anyway

Answer (score 1):

I am not completly sure what you want, but if it's about centering the outer container, you can simply apply `margin: 0 auto` to it. i did that in the snippet below and added `max-width: 500px` to make it visible immediately inside the snippet window (you can of course set that to 1200px).

Note: The centering with `margin: 0 auto` only works if the element has a `position` setting, which was the case in your example.)

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
}
.full-width-row {
  width: 100%; // 100% of entire page so child divs bg color will stretch
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tile {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.tile-content {
  padding: 5%;
}

.left {
  background: #FFC15E;
}

.right {
  background: #3E7F72;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width-row">
  <div class="tile left">
    <div class="tile-content">

      //CONTENT LEFT

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile right">
    <div class="tile-content">

      //CONTENT RIGHT

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was a tough one to explain, would take a second to show in person - picture almost like an 'overlay' wrapper centered across the two child divs that confines them to 1200px

Comment: hmmm - that doesn't really describe it much better, I'm afraid.... If you can add an image of your desired result, maybe?

Comment: How about, restrict the left side from aligning any further than 600px (half 'wrapper' width) from center?

Comment: I think that's what I provided in my snippet - just replace the "max-width: 500px" with "max-width: 1200px" (?)